# How to enable IE 11?

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer

In early days of using Windows 8.1 I remember unninstalling some of it's built-in software (like Adobe Flash Player) and for this reason now I don't have IE. Recently I want to use it for educational purpose but I can't re-enable it. Here is a picture of the error message occured when I try to enable 'Internet Explorer 11' feature:

[image]

I also can't finish 'dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth' giving me a 'normal' error like this:

> Error: 0x800f0906 The source files could not be downloaded. Use the
>   "source" option to specify the location of the files that are required
>   t o restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source
>   location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

I was able to run 'sfc /scannow' successful after some hard-work though.

Also I have an old backed-up image made with 'recimg' which I have set now as a current but when I click 'refresh' option in advanced recovery it wants me to insert installation media. I also tried using this image with 'dism /cleanup-image /restorehealth' as a source but with the same error when not being used.

I also tried to run the Internet Explorer in the backed-up image but it closes immediately after being launch (eg.: 'G:\OnlineWindowsImage\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe').

Comment: When is the last time you installed Windows updates?

Comment: I can't remember but in every case now I don't have any futher to install.

Comment: It shows the date and time on the Windows Update screen!

Comment: I'm using the latest Widows Updates if this is the question. Today it says on the screen.

Comment: Did it _install_ updates today, or only _check_ for updates today? In any case I think it would be a good idea to scan for viruses/malware.

Comment: You get the error ERROR_SXS_TRANSACTION_CLOSURE_INCOMPLETE. I need the logs to see more. Upload the folder C:\Widows\logs\CBS compressed into a zip to a cloud service like OneDrive and post a link here.